# Trouble executing an JPQL query

Tags: mysql, spring, jpql

I'm working with spring boot entity manger using JPQL with queries.
The following query is working correctly:

```
SELECT h, uh FROM Hour h, UserHour uh
```

But now I want to get a single result for which I use the query:

```
SELECT h FROM Hour h INNER JOIN UserHour uh WHERE uh.userId = 1
```

But then the results are zero, which is not expected.

But, when I use the SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM hour
   INNER JOIN user_hour
     ON user_hour.hour_id = hour.hour_id
 WHERE user_hour.user_id = '1'
```

I get the result I want.

Please help me out.

EDIT:

```
List<Object> result = entityManager.createQuery(
                    "select distinct hr " +
                            "from Hour hr " +
                            "join hr.users hu " +
                            "where hu.id = :userID")
                    .setParameter( "userID", 1)
                    .getResultList();
            System.out.println(result);
```

User Entity:

```
package com.timely.backend.models;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String fullname;
    private String email;
    private String creation_date;

    // user roles
    @ElementCollection(targetClass = Role.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Set<Role> roles;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {
            CascadeType.PERSIST,
            CascadeType.MERGE
    })
    @JoinTable(name = "user_hour",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "userId"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "hourId")
    )

    private List<Hour> hours = new ArrayList<>();

    public User() {

    }

    public User(String username, String password, String fullname, String email, String creation_date) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.fullname = fullname;
        this.email = email;
        this.roles = getRoles();
        this.creation_date = creation_date;
    }

    //If user is admin
    public boolean isAdmin() {
        return roles.contains(Role.ADMIN);
    }

    //region Getters & Setters
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public void setFullname(String fullName) {
        this.fullname = fullName;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) { this.email = email; }
    public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) { this.roles = roles; }
    public void setCreation_date(String creation_date) { this.creation_date = creation_date; }

    public int getId() { return id; }
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public String getFullname() {
        return fullname;
    }
    public String getEmail() { return email; }
    public Set<Role> getRoles() { return roles; }
    public String getCreation_date() { return creation_date; }
    //endregion
}
```

UserHour Entity:

```
package com.timely.backend.models;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "user_hour")
public class UserHour {
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public int getHourId() {
        return hourId;
    }

    public void setHourId(int hourId) {
        this.hourId = hourId;
    }

    public UserHour(int userId, int hourId) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.hourId = hourId;
    }

    public UserHour(){

    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private int userId;
    private int hourId;
}
```

Hour Entity:

```
package com.timely.backend.models;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name = "HOUR")
public class Hour {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int hourId;

    private String date;
    private String startTime;
    private String endTime;


    public Hour(int hourId, String date, String startTime, String endTime) {
        this.hourId = hourId;
        this.date = date;
        this.startTime = startTime;
        this.endTime = endTime;
    }

    public Hour(){

    }

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "hours")
    private List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();

    public int gethourId() {
        return hourId;
    }

    public void sethourId(int hourId) {
        this.hourId = hourId;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getStartTime() {
        return startTime;
    }

    public void setStartTime(String startTime) {
        this.startTime = startTime;
    }

    public String getEndTime() {
        return endTime;
    }

    public void setEndTime(String endTime) {
        this.endTime = endTime;
    }
}
```

MySQL query working:

```
SELECT id, date, start_time, end_time FROM hour
JOIN user_hour
     ON user_hour.hour_id = hour.hour_id
 WHERE user_hour.user_id = '1'
```

Problem:
[image]

User Table:

[image]

UserHour Table:

[image]

Hour Table:

[image]

Comment: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-explicit-join

Comment: Your join syntax is off.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'am updated my code, can you have a look?

Comment: Nothing you added helps at all.  We would need to see the entity definitions, in particular the join columns.

Comment: And no, this is still not the correct syntax for joins in JPQL.I linked to the relevant documentation in my first comment. Read it.

Comment: @JBNizet what is the right way then?

Comment: The way explained and shown in the documentation I linked to. Why don't you read it? `select h from UserHour uh join uh.hour h where uh.user.id = 1`. That assumes that UserHour is an entity that has a toOne association with Hour and another toOne association with User.

Comment: @JBNizet I edited my code but the result is still null

Comment: OK, and? Is there an error? If so, which one? And what is the code of your entities?

Comment: @JBNizet Entities are in the new code I added

Comment: OK, but what is your question now? Is there an error? If so, which one?

Comment: @JBNizet My question is that the query is not working I want to get the hour row from the database where the user id is the same as the parameter i've given

Comment: Define "not working". Does it cause an error? If so, which one? If not, then what? Does it return something other than what you expect? If so, what is the content of the three tables, what is the userId you pass to the query, what do you expect to get, and what do you get instead?

Comment: @JBNizet I have no error and the query is not working I have added the MySQL query which is working but i need to translate that query to hibernate query

Comment: Define "not working". Does it return something other than what you expect? If so, what is the content of the three tables, what is the userId you pass to the query, what do you expect to get, and what do you get instead? Those are simple questions that are not rhetorical. If you want help, edit your question and answer them, precisely.

Comment: @JBNizet I've added an image with the output

Comment: what is the content of the three tables, what is the userId you pass to the query, what do you expect to get, and what do you get instead? Those are simple questions that are not rhetorical. If you want help, edit your question and answer them, precisely.

Comment: @JBNizet Check the update

Comment: My guess is that you're not using th database or schema that you think you are, or that you haven't committed the transaction which inserted these 3 rows yet.

Comment: @JBNizet I found the problem, the names in the database in combination with the rest did not match end_time should be endTime for example. Now I have one row returned. Thank you for you time!